# Wake up from hibernation causes reboot instead of resume

Tags: fedora, hibernate

I have installed fresh Fedora 32 Workstation from official .iso image. So far everything works except hibernation. The laptop hibernates without any error and turns off. But when I turn it on it starts like after reboot instead of restoring the previous state.

```
# cat /proc/cmdline 
BOOT_IMAGE=(hd0,msdos1)/vmlinuz-5.7.6-201.fc32.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/fedora_localhost--live-root ro resume=/dev/mapper/fedora_localhost--live-swap rd.lvm.lv=fedora_localhost-live/root rd.lvm.lv=fedora_localhost-live/swap rhgb quiet

# swapon -s
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/dm-1                               partition   11198460    0   -2

# ls -la /dev/mapper/fedora_localhost--live-swap 
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 7 Jul  2 20:37 /dev/mapper/fedora_localhost--live-swap -> ../dm-1
```

Just before turning off journalctl shows:

```
Jul 02 18:19:41 toczka systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Jul 02 18:19:41 toczka systemd[1]: Starting Hibernate...
Jul 02 18:19:41 toczka kernel: PM: Image not found (code -22)
Jul 02 18:19:41 toczka systemd-sleep[2705]: Suspending system...
Jul 02 18:19:41 toczka kernel: PM: hibernation: hibernation entry
Jul 02 18:19:42 toczka kernel: rfkill: input handler enabled
```

I tested the machine with fresh Fedora 31 installation and hibernation works there, then looks like some issue with Fedora 32.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found solution that solves the problem but I'm not sure if this is correct one.

If

```
$ sudo lsinitrd -m | grep 'resume'
```

returns nothing then there is lack of resume module in initrd. To insert it temporarily do:

```
$ sudo dracut -vf -a resume
```

and check again with use of previous command. If it returns 'resume' then try to hibernate and wake up. It should work now.
The change can be set permanently by adding a new rule file into dracut, i.e. in file named:

```
/etc/dracut.conf.d/99-resume.conf
```

that should contain:

```
add_dracutmodules+="resume"
```

Don't forget to update initramfs file by:

```
$ sudo dracut -vf
```

In general this is issue with Fedora 32 installation media. The issue has been described here: [Red Hat Bug 1795422](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1795422)

Answer (score 1):

I've had those problems and solved them the following way:

1. You need a swap partion.
2. Add to the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX = "quiet splash,resume=/dev/sdXn"

where sdXn is the same swap partition you've set into `/etc/fstab`. (e.g. sda5)

Instead of using the the device, you could use the uuid: `resume=UUID=xxxx` where xxxx is the uuid of your swap partition.
Since I don' know fedora, an alternative to the uuid could be:
`resume=/dev/by/uid=xxxx`

Do not forget to to issue `sudo update-grub` after your changes. Reboot then.

Comment: /etc/fstab in Fedora has just device name for the swap, not its UUID

Comment: doesn't matter, as long as you reference the correct partion.  Then take the first solution, it references the device name, so in your case it is "/dev/dm-1". That should be the name in fstab as well